# Open Form to specific record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm struggling with a code I found on Stackoverflow. It keeps on telling me:

> run-time error "424: object required".

I want to double-click on a record within a list box to open a form to the specific record clicked. The value from the record that I need the form to navigate to is found in Column 1 of the list box.

**List Box Name:** `frmDashboardJBCreate`
**Field name in the table:** `JobcardNumber` (numeric field)
**Form Name:** `frmJobcardCreate`
**Table Name:** `tabJobcard_Issue`

The code I tried is the following; but it keeps on giving me the error mentioned above:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmJobcardIssue", , , _
    "[JobcardNumber] = '" & Me.frmDashboardJBCreate.Column(1).Value & "'"
```

Could you please assist me?

Answer (score 0):

If `JobcardNumber` is numeric, don't use single quotes around the parameter.

`ListBox.Column()` is zero-based, so if you want the first column, it's

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmJobcardIssue", , , _
    "[JobcardNumber] = " & Me.frmDashboardJBCreate.Column(0).Value
```

---

Note: `frm` usually stands for "Form", so it is rather confusing if you name a listbox `frmDashboardJBCreate`. Are you sure you have that name right?

Comment: Are you opening the correct form?  You state that your form name is "frmJobcardCreate" yet your OpenForm references "frmJobcardIssue"